# Write and use of uninitialized errors Valgrind

Tags: c, memory-management, valgrind

Basically, I have written a program that, given a set of outputs, the program computes a formula that gives those outputs through genetic programming. In the program I have a function that randomly splits a set of data (inputs and outputs) into training data and test data, given a set of exemplars (fitness data and target data). The way the function works is by dividing the data into four separate arrays, training_cases, test_cases, training_targets and test_targets. Training_cases and test_cases are double arrays that contain inputs while training_targets and test_targets are single arrays that contain the outputs.
Here is the function:

```
struct csv_data *get_test_and_train_data(char *file_name, double split) {
    double ***exemplars = parse_exemplars(file_name);
    double **fitness = exemplars[0];
    double *targs = *exemplars[1];

    // Get lengths of the arrays.
    int fitness_len = get_2d_arr_length(fitness);
    int targs_len =  get_double_arr_length(targs);
    int col_size = get_double_arr_length(fitness[0]);

    // randomize the index order
    int fits_split_i = (int)(floor(fitness_len * split));
    int *fits_rand_idxs = random_indexes(fitness_len);

    // Split the cases and targets up according to the index at which to split.
    // Leave space for NULL/NAN at the end.
    double **training_cases = malloc((sizeof(double *) * fits_split_i) + 1);
    double **test_cases = malloc((sizeof(double *) * (fitness_len - fits_split_i)) + 1);
    double *training_targets = malloc((sizeof(double) * fits_split_i) + 1);
    double *test_targets = malloc(sizeof(double) * (targs_len - fits_split_i) + 1);

    // Allocate the inner arrays.
    for (int i = 0; i < fits_split_i; i++) {
        training_cases[i] = malloc(sizeof(double) * col_size);

        if (i >= fitness_len) {
            test_cases[i - fits_split_i] = malloc(sizeof(double) * col_size);
        }
    }

    int rand_i;

    // Split the fitness and target data into training and test cases.
    for (int i = 0; i < fitness_len; i++) {
        rand_i = fits_rand_idxs[i];

        if (i >= fits_split_i) {
            test_cases[i - fits_split_i] = fitness[rand_i];
            test_targets[i - fits_split_i] = targs[rand_i]; // line 636
        } else {
            training_cases[i] = fitness[rand_i];
            training_targets[i] = targs[rand_i]; // line 639

        }
    }

    // Set last index to NULL/NAN to allow for easier looping of arrays
    training_cases[fits_split_i] = NULL; // line 645
    test_cases[fitness_len - fits_split_i] = NULL; // line 646
    training_targets[fits_split_i] = NAN; // line 647
    test_targets[targs_len - fits_split_i] = NAN; // line 648
```

The issue is I am getting multiple errors (write and uninitialized value errors).
This is the output of valgrind:

```
==5049== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==5049==    at 0x4053A4: get_test_and_train_data (util.c:639)
==5049==    by 0x4027BE: setup (pony_gp.c:740)
==5049==    by 0x40286C: main (pony_gp.c:774)
==5049==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==5049==    at 0x405161: get_test_and_train_data (util.c:599)
==5049== 
==5049== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==5049==    at 0x405343: get_test_and_train_data (util.c:636)
==5049==    by 0x4027BE: setup (pony_gp.c:740)
==5049==    by 0x40286C: main (pony_gp.c:774)
==5049==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==5049==    at 0x405161: get_test_and_train_data (util.c:599)
==5049== 
==5049== Invalid write of size 8
==5049==    at 0x4053D0: get_test_and_train_data (util.c:645)
==5049==    by 0x4027BE: setup (pony_gp.c:740)
==5049==    by 0x40286C: main (pony_gp.c:774)
==5049==  Address 0x5593eb0 is 672 bytes inside a block of size 673 alloc'd
==5049==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5049==    by 0x4051F1: get_test_and_train_data (util.c:614)
==5049==    by 0x4027BE: setup (pony_gp.c:740)
==5049==    by 0x40286C: main (pony_gp.c:774)
==5049== 
==5049== Invalid write of size 8
==5049==    at 0x4053EE: get_test_and_train_data (util.c:646)
==5049==    by 0x4027BE: setup (pony_gp.c:740)
==5049==    by 0x40286C: main (pony_gp.c:774)
==5049==  Address 0x5594028 is 296 bytes inside a block of size 297 alloc'd
==5049==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5049==    by 0x40520D: get_test_and_train_data (util.c:615)
==5049==    by 0x4027BE: setup (pony_gp.c:740)
==5049==    by 0x40286C: main (pony_gp.c:774)
==5049== 
==5049== Invalid write of size 8
==5049==    at 0x405411: get_test_and_train_data (util.c:647)
==5049==    by 0x4027BE: setup (pony_gp.c:740)
==5049==    by 0x40286C: main (pony_gp.c:774)
==5049==  Address 0x5594310 is 672 bytes inside a block of size 673 alloc'd
==5049==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5049==    by 0x405226: get_test_and_train_data (util.c:616)
==5049==    by 0x4027BE: setup (pony_gp.c:740)
==5049==    by 0x40286C: main (pony_gp.c:774)
==5049== 
==5049== Invalid write of size 8
==5049==    at 0x405434: get_test_and_train_data (util.c:648)
==5049==    by 0x4027BE: setup (pony_gp.c:740)
==5049==    by 0x40286C: main (pony_gp.c:774)
==5049==  Address 0x5594488 is 296 bytes inside a block of size 297 alloc'd
==5049==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5049==    by 0x405242: get_test_and_train_data (util.c:617)
==5049==    by 0x4027BE: setup (pony_gp.c:740)
==5049==    by 0x40286C: main (pony_gp.c:774)
==5049==
```

My guess is that most of these errors are due to an improper allocation in the beginning of the functions. I have tested all other functions used to ensure that they are returning the right values.

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT 1**

Christoph Freundl's eliminated all the write errors, so now I have the uninitialized errors to fix. I have a feeling that parse_exemplars() is causing them, so here is parse_exemplars:

```
/**
* Parse a CSV file. Parse the fitness case and split the data into
* test and train data. in the fitness case file each row is an exemplar
* and each dimension is in a column. The last column is the target value
* of the exemplar. The function returns a third degree pointer with the
* fitness data as the first element and the targets as the second element.
* The fitness data is structured as a 2D array and the target data is
* represented as a one dimensional array.
*    file_name: Name of CSV file with a header.
*/
double ***parse_exemplars(char *file_name) {
    csv_reader *reader = init_csv(file_name, ',');

    double **fitness_cases, *targets;
    int num_columns = get_num_column(reader);
    int num_lines = get_num_lines(reader);

    // leave space for NULL
    fitness_cases = malloc(sizeof(double *) * num_lines);

    for (int i = 0; i < num_lines; i++) {
        fitness_cases[i] = malloc(sizeof(double) * num_columns);
    }

    // leave space for NAN
    targets = malloc(sizeof(double) * (num_lines));

    csv_line *row;
    int f_i = 0;
    int t_i = 0;

    // Ignore the header
    next_line(reader);

    // Loop through to get target and fitness values.
    while ((row = readline(reader))) {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < num_columns; i++) {
            if (i == num_columns - 1) { // Last element of array is the target/desired output.
                targets[t_i++] = atof(row->content[i]);
            }
            else {
                // The arguments/inputs.
                fitness_cases[f_i][i] = atof(row->content[i]);
            }
        }

        // take the [i-1]th index because fitness cases has [num_columns-1] elements.
        fitness_cases[f_i][i-1] = (double)NAN;
        f_i++;
    }

    // Set last index to NULL/NAN for easier looping.
    fitness_cases[f_i] = NULL;
    targets[t_i] = (double)NAN;

    // Wrap the fitness cases and targets in a 3rd degree pointer
    double ***results = malloc(sizeof(double **) * 2);
    double *tmp[] = { targets };
    results[0] = fitness_cases;
    results[1] = tmp;

    free(row);
    free(reader);

    return results;
}
```

Comment: Try to avoid being a http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer

Comment: Please indicate (via comments) which of your quoted lines are the lines indicated via line numbers by valgrind.

Comment: I already did comment the lines indicated in valgrind. Also, yes I'm aware that that's not good practice but I figured with correct documentation it would be alright, because the function returns a double array and a single array since it gets the fitness and target data in the same function, one being a double array the other being a single array. What suggestions would you have to reduce the indirectness?

Comment: As to the ones indicating malloc, all the memory you malloc is not initialized by default.  If you were to use calloc() to init the memory then you probably won't see these valgrind errors.

As for the one on line 599 (stack creation) I'm not sure what that is referring to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Invalid writes

For the last elements of the arrays `training_cases`, `test_cases`, `training_targets` and `test_targets` only one byte is allocated. However, these are accessed either as a `double` (8 bytes) or as a `double *` (again 8 bytes because of 64-bit architecture) each: in the assignments in lines 645-648 the `NULL` and `NAN` values get implicitly converted. These assignments therefore cause the "invalid write" errors.

Change the allocation of e.g. `training_cases` to

```
double **training_cases = malloc((sizeof(double *) * (fits_split_i + 1));
```

and the other allocations similarly and you should be fine.

#### Uninitialised values

There is an error in `parse_examplars()`: `results[1]` receives the locally declared array `tmp` which becomes invalid when leaving the function.

My suggestion: define a

```
struct exemplars {
    double** fitness_cases;
    double* targets;
}
```

and use a variable of this type instead of `double ***results`.

Comment: Ahhh of course, such a silly mistake. That fixes the write errors, but I am still left with initialized errors at line 636 and 639. If the rest of the code is fine, then that must mean it's the function that returns the exemplars, right?

Comment: Yes, without knowing what `parse_exemplars()` does it is hard to tell what is leading to the uninitialised value reads. You could try to add a debug output of the value of `rand_i` to get a hint which elements of the array are not initialised.

Comment: Would it be helpful if i uploaded the function here? I posted a question about it previously (Titled invalid write size of 8 valgrind).

Comment: I assume that meanwhile you have a corrected version of the function and it is no longer like the one in the question you mention, so please go ahead.

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly. I was considering using a struct but I wasn't sure because it would only be used in the program once.